# how condition_variable and unique_lock works for thread safe list

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to use condition variable and unique lock to make a thread safe list. However,  I met some problems, it seems the list operation is not thread safe.

I have create an ***`atomic_flag`*** to test if it is thread safe.
Basically, when I operate the list, I will first check if the atomic flag was set, and *clear* the atomic flag when the list operation is done.

In my thought, the atomic flag operates under the mutex protection, so each time when I ***`test_and_set`*** the atomic flag, I should see the initial value should be false, but when I run the test code, I found it is not so.

Can anyone help me and point out what wrong with the code, why the list operation is not thread safe with the condition variable's protection?

Thanks
The test code is as the following:

```
using namespace std;
//list element
class myitem
{
public:
    myitem() { val = -1; };
    myitem(int n, int c){ val = n; chr = c; };
    int val;
    char chr;
};

// mutex and condition variable to protect the list.
std::mutex mymtx;
condition_variable mycv;
    // the list to be protected
    std::list<myitem> mylist;  
    // the atomic flag to test.
    std::atomic_flag testlk = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void datagenthread(char c)
{
   int n = 10*1000*1000;
   while(n >0)
   {
      myitem item(n, c);
      {
         unique_lock<mutex> lk(mymtx); // get the lock
         if( testlk.test_and_set() != false) { // test the atomic flag
            cout<<"error in thread"<<c<<" for test lock"<<endl; 
         } 
         mylist.push_back(item);
         testlk.clear(); // clear the atomic before unlock.
      }
      mycv.notify_one();
      n--;
   }
}

void datareadthread()
{
   int count = 0;
   int readc = 0;
   while ( count <2)  {
      {
         unique_lock<mutex> lk(mymtx); // acquire lock
         while ( mylist.size() <= 0)   {
            mycv.wait(lk); // block until the thread get notified and get lock again.
         }
         if( testlk.test_and_set()!= false)  {// test the atomic flag.
            cout<<"error in reader thread"<<endl; 
         }
         myitem readitem;
         readitem = mylist.front();
         mylist.pop_front();
         readc++;
         if ( readitem.val == 1)
         {
            cout<<" get last one last item form a thread,"<<endl;
            count++;
         }
         testlk.clear(); // clear the atomic flag before unlock
      }//unique_lock destruct
   }//end while
}
int main()
{
   std::thread cons(   datareadthread);
   std::thread gen1(   datagenthread, 'a');
   std::thread gen2(   datagenthread, 'b');
   gen1.join();
   gen2.join();
   cons.join();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't see any thread errors here http://ideone.com/ld07Du

Comment: I build it under the arm linux platform and got a lot of errors like:   error in reader thread
error in reader thread
error in reader thread
error in reader thread
error in reader thread
error in threada for test lock
error in threada for test lock
error in threada for test lock

Comment: How do you build it?

Answer (score 0):

`testlk` default constructor initializes it to unspecified state, so at first iteration initial value be something other than `false`. You should initialize it with cleared state like this:

```
std::atomic_flag testlk = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
```

Comment: I have changed my code to initialize the atomic_flag, but the problem is still there. I am running the code under an arm Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason, it seems I link some wrong libs which caused the mutex/condition_var not working properly.